# fail2ban: how to customize filters and based on time-occurs?

Tags: fail2ban

I have an application, and seems it was attacked by huge ips.

- log file: `/root/kitty/nohup.out`
- process: kitty
- port: 8888

```
[2021-08-31 10:02:20] [ALL] 168.138.142.22:50384 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:21] [ALL] 168.138.78.185:57728 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:21] [ALL] 168.138.78.185:57614 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:21] [ALL] 168.138.146.133:59078 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 140.238.152.56:32884 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 168.138.146.133:57606 tunnel established
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 168.138.146.133:57606 SSL session reused
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 140.238.152.56:32976 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 140.238.152.56:48210 incoming connection
[2021-08-31 10:02:22] [ALL] 168.138.78.185:52390 tunnel established
```

What I want to do is :

1. tail the log file for the past 60 seconds logs.
2. block the ips which exceeds the request limit, such as 2 req/second

How to do this by fail2ban ?

## UPDATED

Could you please tell me which file to configure, and then run which command ?

I modified the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` , added the content

```
[DEFAULT]

maxretry = 5 
findtime = 300 
bantime = 3600
bantime.increment = true
bantime.factor = 2
```

restarted the fail2ban service, nothing happened.

I created a new filter named `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/kitty.conf`, its content is:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[DEFAULT]
_daemon = kitty
```

also add this content to `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf`

```
[kitty]
enabled = true
maxretry = 1000
findtime = 100
bantime = 3600
bantime.increment = true
bantime.factor = 2
logpath = /root/kitty/nohup.out
```

then restart the fail2ban service, now I saw `kitty` was in the list,

```
# fail2ban-client status kitty
Status for the jail: kitty
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed: 0
|  `- File list:    /root/kitty/nohup.out
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
   `- Banned IP list:
```

but still there's no IP blocked ( I can see the tons of malicious IP coming out... )

Could you please tell me which file to configure, and then run which command ?

Comment: It has been a while since I modified fail2ban, but I think you need to lower maxretry to like 2, and how is fail2ban recording an attempt? You might have to tell it what to look for with a regex.. see https://number1.co.za/fail2ban-custom-filters-and-testing-regexs-against-existing-logs/

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you are asking for would be achieved with these 2 parameters in the DEFAULT section of your jail file.

```
[DEFAULT]
maxretry = 2
findtime = 1
```

But that is not practical, it's too strict and you will most likely ban legit IPs just trying to have normal access.

```
[DEFAULT]
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
```

Now, you can see in that log that whoever is "attacking" is using some IP rotation script, so you can do something more effective like and incremental ban time (for repeated offenders). Try something like:

```
[DEFAULT]
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
bantime = 3600
bantime.increment = true
bantime.factor = 2
```

The above will double the ban time if you have a repeated offender, and double every time that IP is caught. Enough to cause their scripts to fail and desist.

If you want these actions for a specific service just include the options in the specific service of the jail file instead of `[DEFAULT]`.

Remember to restart/reload the service after making any changes.

Comment: thanks, but do I need to configure the time format for fail2ban?  so that it could recorgnize `[2021-08-31 10:02:22]`

Comment: They look like standard time stamps to me, fail2ban will read them without further configuration.

Comment: Could you please tell me which file to configure, and then run which command ?  I modified the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` , added the content you suggested, and also created a new file named `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/kitty.conf`, its content is copied from `sshd`, and restarted the fail2ban service, nothing happened. no ip is blocked. from `fail2ban-client status kitty` I can see the log file was monitoring.

Comment: I added additional information to my post. thanks @Gary

Comment: The configuration you posted allows 1000 requests (maxretry = 1000) in a time space of 100 secons (findtime = 100). That is 10 requests per second, which I am sure is not what you wanted to do.